# Connecting to a SQL Server database running in a Docker container from another docker container

Tags: sql-server, docker

I am creating a database in a Docker container via the following

```
docker run -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "SA_PASSWORD=YourStrong@Passw0rd" -p 1433:1433 --network MyAppNetwork --name MyAppDb -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest-ubuntu
```

I am then running my ASP.NET Core 3.0 application

```
docker run -p 5000:80 -e "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development" --network MyAppNetwork --name MyApp myimage
```

Inside the app there is a connection string

```
Data Source=MyAppDb;Initial Catalog=MyAppDb;User ID=sa;Password=YourStrong@Passw0rd
```

and I perpetually get the error

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

I have tried `MyAppDb,1433` `localhost` `localhost,1433`... nothing works

Docker documentation says you should be able to refer to other docker containers via their name as long as they are on the same network, but its not behaving as expected for me. I did try not specifying a network so the containers are just defaulting to the bridge, but nothing changed.

Note: I can connect to the database perfectly fine from my host machine, but from within the other docker container, nothing works.

Any ideas?

-- update --

`docker network inspect MyAppNetwork`

```
[
    {
        "Name": "MyAppNetwork",
        "Id": "2f334b2df38c199ef423fdbe65c15e33b43d983e91a3398d75f0d988d5588c13",
        "Created": "2019-10-03T10:40:40.3165785Z",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": {},
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.19.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.19.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
"f3106bc710fe760e257dd05aace7e76827d953600e5520556b040706f10246fb": {
                "Name": "MyAppDb",
                "EndpointID": "c4c58df89b4117674a0db57dfe276086eb48dda36fcc6a0989425b65fc130c41",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:13:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.19.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {}
]
```

Comment: "IP packet forwarding is governed by the ip_forward system parameter. Packets can only pass between containers if this parameter is 1", ref: [Understand container communication](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/container-communication/)

Comment: By default --ip-forward=true

Comment: You're also using a custom network. What does `docker network inspect MyAppNetwork` tell you?

Comment: ill edit it into the original question - done - nothing anything wrong?

Comment: Whilst running the `MyAppDb` and `MyApp` containers should appear inside MyAppNetwork's `"Containers": {}` collection. `MyApp` should be able to connect to `172.19.some.address,1433` using the IPv4Address indicated against `MyAppDb` in the containers collection. [User-defined networks](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/#user-defined-networks) has more information about this. If DNS is properly configured and running inside the network, MyApp should also be able to resolve and connect to `MyAppDb,1433`.

Comment: Updated network details with the db running - but obviously the app will not be in the list of running containers because it crashes as soon as it tries to connect to the db. My problem is that I really really really dont want to have to go and figure out the IP address of the container on each run, it has to be by name or else its a bad enough dev experience to just give up on docker.

Comment: I have the same problem since the update to 3.0. Is there a solution now?

Comment: Not that I know of, I completely gave up and just went back to using links despite the fact that they are deprecated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I spent many hours on this trying to do it "properly" but eventually I just gave up and went back to using the deprecated Links feature based solution within a docker-compose file

https://docs.docker.com/network/links/

Worked immediately without any issues what so ever. I will revisit this when the next major update to Docker comes out and removes the Link feature.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.5"

networks:
  myappnetwork:
    name: myappnetwork

services:
  myapp:
    build: .
    restart: always
    container_name: myapp
    depends_on: [myappdb]
    environment:
      ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT: Development
    networks:
      - myappnetwork
    ports:
      - 5000:80
    links:
      - myappdb
  myappdb:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest-ubuntu
    restart: always
    container_name: myappdb
    environment:
      ACCEPT_EULA: Y
      SA_PASSWORD: YourStrong@Passw0rd
    networks:
      - myappnetwork
    ports:
      - 1433:1433
```

dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.0 AS build
WORKDIR /app

# copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.sln .
COPY MyApp/*.csproj ./MyApp/
RUN dotnet restore

# copy everything else and build app
COPY MyApp/. ./MyApp/
WORKDIR /app/MyApp
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.0 AS runtime
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app/MyApp/out ./
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyApp.dll"]
```

appsettings.json

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Data Source=myappdb,1433;Initial Catalog=myappdb;User ID=sa;Password=YourStrong@Passw0rd"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try following:

After you start running the SQL container, get the IP of the container by

`docker inspect MyAppDb | grep IPAddress`

If this is a Linux server you should be able to connect another container by the IP address. Or you can use the IP of the host server that docker containers run.

Additionally, you may need to add:

`Trusted_Connection=false;` attribute to your connection string.

Comment: I have tried to go down this path, and it lead me to a dead end as the IP address that returns is unresolvable from within the other container. I may have been able to fix it eventually, but its still a dead end as there is no point in a 1 command start process that then needs a manual step to make it work.