# .Net error connecting to SQL Server in docker container

Tags: asp.net, docker, sql-server-express, sqlcmd

I have 2 docker containers, one with sqlexpress and one with my asp.net app. Both of these containers are in the same network and see each other. I can connect to the database from the host machine with SQL Management Studio and from my app container using:

```
./sqlcmd -S sql,1433 -U sa -P Password1! -C
```

But when I connect with my app, I get:

> The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the
> instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow
> remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 40 - Could not
> open a connection to SQL Server: Could not open a connection to SQL
> Server)

The connection string I use is this:

```
"WebDBConnection": "Server=sql,1433;Database=EmerseDB;Integrated Security=false;User ID=sa;Password=Password1!;"
```

I tried different combinations of arguments in the connection string, with/without trusted certificate, integrated security, port, Data source instead of server, etc. Nothing works.
I also use the dbcontext like so:

```
builder.Services.AddDbContextPool<WebDBContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("WebDBConnection")));
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Connecting to a SQL Server database running in a Docker container from another docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58217700/connecting-to-a-sql-server-database-running-in-a-docker-container-from-another-d)

Comment: @AaronBertrand not exactly, since I hae already setup the network and can connect from within my docker container with the sqlcmd tool. So the connection between containers is clearly present. I can also ping the ip and tcp connect to the port from .Net. Only the .Net db connection fails

Comment: Ensure both Docker containers are on the same network without network restrictions. Verify SQL Server Express listens on port 1433 and allows remote connections. Use "Data Source" instead of "Server" in the connection string. Check SQL Server authentication, network connectivity, and container names. Review SQL Server logs and test connection with a simple .NET Core app to isolate issues. Double-check connection string for typos.